# Where we can get documents for Sharepoint Workflow using visual studio?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new to Sharepoint . I want to know the sharepoint workflow using visual studio. Please Share if you have any Documents and where we can get the documents?

Thanks in advance.

Ramadurai U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check e.g. [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231606%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/03/27/sharepoint-workflow-development-with-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/416393/Create-a-Workflow-using-Visual-Studio-2010).